# click on element using selenium returns error - python - myspace

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, click, myspace

I use selenium with python 3.2 and works fine for most of sites but when I tried to click a button on the share page it gives me error
I used two ways as below

```
x = br.find_element_by_css_selector('BUTTON.primary')
x.click()
```

or using action chains

```
x = br.find_element_by_css_selector('BUTTON.primary')
webdriver.ActionChains(br).move_to_element(x).click(x).perform()
```

the link I tried is [here](https://myspace.com/post?u=http://yoursportsfeeder.com/baseball/mlb-news-rumors-and-injury-roundup-for-march-28/&t=MLB%20news,%20rumors%20and%20injury%20roundup%20for%20March%2028%20%E2%80%93%20your%20sports%20feeder&c=)

i used also send_keys(Keys.Enter) and Keys.Return

Comment: `"it gives me error"` - what error exactly?

Comment: I appears to me that you are trying yo click on a button that is not yet enabled because you need to input some data before clicking in it.